# Set XSL variable with a script generated value

Tags: javascript, variables, xslt, sqrt

I am trying to get a value generated by a variable in `XSL`

```
            <xsl:variable name="Value">
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var DistX = <xsl:value-of select="DistX"/>;
                var DistY = <xsl:value-of select="DistY"/>;
                var PadSize = <xsl:value-of select="PadSize"/>;
                var Value = Math.trunc(Math.sqrt(((DistX/PadSize*100) * (DistX/PadSize*100))  +    ((DistY/PadSize*100) * (DistY/PadSize*100))   ),0.1);
               document.write(Value);
                       console.log(Value);              
            </script>
            
            </xsl:variable>
                
            <xsl:value-of select="$Value"></xsl:value-of>
```

The result of this display in table `<td>`:

```
var DistX = 0.9;
var DistY = 0.3;
var PadSize = 2.6;
var Value = Math.trunc(Math.sqrt(((DistX/PadSize*100) * (DistX/PadSize*100)) + ((DistY/PadSize*100) * (DistY/PadSize*100)) ),0.1);
document.write(Value);
console.log(Value);
```

and not calculated value 54% I want make an `if` statement on this value to change the font color.

[bad display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM3Mp.png)

[good display made by paint power ;)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDhxp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Usually XSLT is executed before and independent of any JavaScript execution thus any sequence which might make sense is to simply create script element doing the computation and outputting its computed value:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
            var DistX = <xsl:value-of select="DistX"/>;
            var DistY = <xsl:value-of select="DistY"/>;
            var PadSize = <xsl:value-of select="PadSize"/>;
            var Value = Math.trunc(Math.sqrt(((DistX/PadSize*100) * (DistX/PadSize*100))  +    ((DistY/PadSize*100) * (DistY/PadSize*100))   ),0.1);
           document.write(Value);
        </script>
```

without nesting it into an `xsl:variable`.

Note that `document.write` is not supported in client-side script in Mozilla browsers if the XSLT is also run client-side (e.g. with `<?xml-stylesheet?>` pi).

Comment: AFAICT, the problem is not the variable, but the `xsl:value-of` instruction that reduces the variable to its string-value.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, to me it seemed the variable only complicated things and I tried to simplify the presented code as much as possible so that it works; for that I don't see any need for the variable.

Comment: It's quite possible that the variable is not needed. But that's not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running XSLT in the browser, you could upgrade to XSLT 3.0 by using Saxon-JS, and then do it all in XSLT (no Javascript needed) by writing

```
    <xsl:variable name="Value" select="round(math:sqrt(((DistX/PadSize*100) *
      (DistX/PadSize*100)) + ((DistY/PadSize*100) * (DistY/PadSize*100))))"/>
```

(You seem to be calling Math.trunc() with two arguments, I'm not sure what that does exactly, but there will be an XPath equivalent).